# Delphi, Restore, runtime error message,.Delphi

Tags: windows-11, runtime-error, delphi

I received an error message during the operation of the program and mistakenly said "do not show more of these types of errors".
How can I get this error message back again?

Delphi version is 10.4, Os Windows 11.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't forget to tick the answer to indicate it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here

- Click on **Tools**
- Expand **Debugger**
- Expand **Embarcadero Debuggers**
- Click on **Language Exceptions**

You will see a list of error types it is ignoring.  Just uncheck the one you asked it to ignore.

Comment: Thank you. Its works.  Only one problem: What error type. Simple - Last in list.